# SQL Server: Count distinct occurrences in one field by value in another

Tags: sql-server

Currently I'm writing two queries to count distinct occurrences of fieldOne for each possible value of fieldTwo. How can I do this in one query? Thanks

```
select 
    count(*) from(select distinct(fieldOne) from myTable where fieldTwo= 'valueOne')x 


select 
    count(*) from(select distinct(fieldOne) from myTable where fieldTwo = 'valueTwo') y
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with `cross apply` to remove the need to know the possible values in `fieldTwo`:

```
select twos.FieldTwo, count(1)
from (select distinct fieldTwo from MyTable) twos
  cross apply (select distinct t.fieldOne
               from MyTable t
               where t.fieldTwo = twos.FieldTwo) ones
group by twos.FieldTwo
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `CASE` statement

```
SELECT  COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN  FIELDTWO= 'VALUEONE' THEN FIELDONE END) X ,
COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN  FIELDTWO= 'VALUETWO' THEN FIELDONE END)Y
FROM MYTABLE
```